# How to add arraylist in for loop?

Tags: android, for-loop, arraylist

I use the following method in my database class. It is not working and i do not see where the problem is. Maybe someone can help me.

```
public ArrayList<Profile> getAllProfile() {

        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Profile profile = new Profile();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER, null);
        ArrayList<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList<>();

        if (cursor!=null){
            for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext() ){

                profile.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID)));
                profile.setFirstName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FIRST_NAME)));
                profile.setLastName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LAST_NAME)));
                profile.setFatherName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FATHER)));
                profile.setAge(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(AGE)));
                profile.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EMAIL)));
                profile.setGender(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(GENDER)));
                profile.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PHONE_NUMBER)));
                profiles.add(profile);
                App.myLog("is : " +profile.getFirstName());
            }
            cursor.close();
            return profiles;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Also, you're adding a reference to the same object over and over again.

Comment: move the profile object inside the loop

Comment: That cursor.close() statement right before the return null statement should probably be removed.  If that were to execute, cursor would be null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be, that you are creating only one instance of your `Profile` object before the loop and adding only this instance to your list in your loop.

So change your code as follows:

```
public ArrayList getAllProfile() 
    {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER, null);

        if (cursor != null)
        {
            ArrayList<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList<>();

            for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext() )
            {
                Profile profile = new Profile(); // create a new instance in your loop, instead only creating one instance before the loop
                profile.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID)));
                profile.setFirstName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FIRST_NAME)));
                profile.setLastName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LAST_NAME)));
                profile.setFatherName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FATHER)));
                profile.setAge(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(AGE)));
                profile.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EMAIL)));
                profile.setGender(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(GENDER)));
                profile.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PHONE_NUMBER)));
                profiles.add(profile);
                App.myLog("is : " +profile.getFirstName());
            }
            cursor.close();
            return profiles;
        }

        if(cursor != null)
        {
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks buddy , my terrible mistake , its work now thank you

Comment: @MoHMaD No problem :) Would be pleased if you could accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: buddy i cant , i'm still under 15 reputation